# Linking problem on static variable inside a DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I need to link a DLL (named common), to another DLL (named toolkit).

I got a LNK2001 error (I'm Using MSVC2019) to ONE (and just one) symbol present in the common DLL.

In the source file (.cpp) I have:

```
int64_t TimingUtil::timestamp_calibration_offset = 0;
```

In the header file I have:

```
class TimingUtil:
       public  Singleton<TimingUtil> {
            friend class Singleton<TimingUtil>;
            ....
            static int64_t  timestamp_calibration_offset;
```

So the definition of the same symbol.

That symbol is used in some inline function INSIDE the header file:

```
static inline uint64_t getTimeStamp() {
try
{
   return (boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()- EPOCH + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(timestamp_calibration_offset)).total_milliseconds();
}
```

The Toolkit dll uses this inline function in some code.

When linking the TOOLKIT  dll, I got:

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol (timestamp_calibration_offset)
```

The strange fact is that using `dumpbin` I found the correct symbol in the common.dll, in the import lib common.lib, and also in the export.def produced by the CMake launched with:

```
-DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=TRUE
```

The "decorated" name of the symbol is correct.

So why the second DLL (toolkit), sees all my method and functions present in common.dll, except for that?

EDIT. MINIMAL CONFIGURATION
File TimingUtil.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
namespace utility {
            /*
             Class for give some method util for timing purpose
             */
               class TimingUtil{
           public:
  //          public utility::Singleton<TimingUtil> {
  //              friend class utility::Singleton<TimingUtil>;
                const uint32_t      calibration_offset_bound;
                const bool          calibration_enable_status;
                //const std::string   remote_ntp_server;
                 static  int64_t  timestamp_calibration_offset;
                static const char* formats[];
                static const size_t formats_n;

            protected:
                TimingUtil();

            public:
                TimingUtil(int a);

                 static  int64_t getTimeStamp() 
                {
                    return timestamp_calibration_offset;
                }


            };
}
```

FILE TimingUtil.cpp

```
#include "TimingUtil.h"


using namespace utility;
int64_t TimingUtil::timestamp_calibration_offset = 0;


const size_t TimingUtil::formats_n = 11;
TimingUtil::TimingUtil():
calibration_enable_status(true),
calibration_offset_bound(2)//,remote_ntp_server("stringa")
{}
TimingUtil::TimingUtil(int a):
    calibration_enable_status(true),
    calibration_offset_bound(a)
{

}
```

FILE common/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(common)

MESSAGE(" CMAKELIST common")


SET(common_lib_src utility/TimingUtil.cpp)




IF (BUILD_FORCE_STATIC  )
  ADD_LIBRARY(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${common_lib_src})
ELSE (BUILD_FORCE_STATIC)
  ADD_LIBRARY(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${common_lib_src})
  set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VERSION 1.0.0 SOVERSION 1)
ENDIF (BUILD_FORCE_STATIC)




FILE(GLOB files "./*.h")
INSTALL(FILES ${files} DESTINATION include/utility)
INSTALL(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        DESTINATION "lib"
        PERMISSIONS OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ GROUP_READ WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE)
```

Library toolkit, minimal:
File AbstractControlUnit.h

```
#include "../../common/utility/TimingUtil.h"
#include <string>

namespace cu {
        namespace control_manager {


            class AbstractControlUnit {

            public:

                AbstractControlUnit(const std::string& _control_unit_type,
                    const std::string& _control_unit_id,
                    const std::string& _control_unit_param);
                //!push system dataset
                 int pushInputDataset();
            };
        }
}
```

File AbstractControlUnit.cpp

```
#include "AbstractControlUnit.h"
//! Contructor with type and id
using namespace cu::control_manager;
using namespace utility;
AbstractControlUnit::AbstractControlUnit(const std::string& _control_unit_type,
                                         const std::string& _control_unit_id,
                                         const std::string& _control_unit_param)
                                         {
                                         }

int AbstractControlUnit::pushInputDataset() {
    TimingUtil prova(34);
    return     TimingUtil::getTimeStamp();


}
```

File cu_toolkit/CMakeLists.txt

```
project(cutoolkit)

SET(cu_lib_src control_manager/AbstractControlUnit.cpp)


IF (BUILD_FORCE_STATIC)
     ADD_LIBRARY(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${cu_lib_src})
 ELSE ()
     ADD_LIBRARY(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${cu_lib_src})

     set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VERSION 1.0.0 SOVERSION 1)

 ENDIF ()

 set (WINCOMMONBUILDLIBPATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/common")
 SET (ALL_WINDOWS_LIBS "-LIBPATH:${WINCOMMONBUILDLIBPATH} common.lib")



SET(BUILD_LIBRARY ${ALL_WINDOWS_LIBS} )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${BUILD_LIBRARY})
```

And finally the general CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
MESSAGE("framework CMakeLists")
IF(WIN32)
add_definitions(-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x601)
ENDIF(WIN32)
project(framework)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(common)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(cu_toolkit)
```

The CMakeSettings.json is:

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "-DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=TRUE -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE",
      "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
      "ctestCommandArgs": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

What happens, if you see the AbstractControlUnit.cpp is that inside the 
pushInputDataset() method, there's a call to a Constructor of TimingUtil and a call to the static variable TimingUtil::timestamp_calibration_offset.

The system links correctly the constructor (you don't receive any undefined symbol about that, because it is exported via 
"-DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=TRUE -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE"  cmake command args.
But the system doesn't link the static variable.

I "solved" that stuff declaring as __declspec(dllexport) inside the declaration of the static variable in TimingUtil.h

```
static __declspec(dllexport) int64_t  timestamp_calibration_offset;
```

and adding the declaration of

```
__declspec(dllexport) int64_t  utility::TimingUtil::timestamp_calibration_offset;
```

inside the AbstractControlUnit.cpp

Now it links, but I'm not even sure the two variables are the same. In principle I just declared another one in the second library.
What I can see is the different behaviour between linking the constructor and the static member of the class.

Sorry for the late answer.

Comment: How does `getTimeStamp` function know that `timestamp_calibration_offset` is from `TimingUtil`? Should you not have the `TimingUtil::` prefix before the variable name? Or have I missed something?

Comment: @AdrianMole I assume `getTimeStamp` is a member function of `TimingUtil`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Fair point, I guess, as it's an "inline function in the header!" But I think there should be some kind of switchable `__declspec(dllexport)/(dllimport)` qualifier on the `TimingUtil` class. And why doesn't the unresolved symbol name have the `TimingUtil::` qualifier?

Comment: @AdrianMole. Yes is a member function of TimingUtil. I can add also that this problem disappear if you link statically. This happens only with dynamic library

Comment: Then my second point in my previous comment could be the issue! How does your EXE's compilation unit know that the `TimingUtil` class (and its members) are to be imported from a DLL? You need to have the `__declspec(dllimport)` attribute on the `class` declaration for the linker to resolve it from the DLL's export library.

Comment: Everything you say implies that `common.lib` is not getting linked.

Comment: @AdrianMole Should not need TimingUtil:: qualifier, because the inline function is a method of TimingUtil, and the class have the definition of "timestamp_calibration_offset".

Comment: Instead of declspec all the methods and classes of my dll, because I'm using a code that should be multi-S.O., I used the CMAKE argument -DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=TRUE that should export all symbols. I cannot change all the headers of the common and toolkit library. Anyway, the common library contains more than 300 symbols that the toolkit library links correctly. I get ONLY 1 unresolved symbol. If I don't link common.lib / dll  I get over than 300 unresolved symbols.

Comment: The option "-DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=TRUE" provides only that resulted library will **export** all its symbols. But **importing** the symbols (`dllimport`) is still required for being able to use them.

Comment: BTW, you show us several chunks of code, but it is not completely clear how they are incorporated. Please, prepare [mcve]. Also, as you use `cmake` tag, please include corresponding `CMakeLists.txt` into the question.

Comment: Prepared minimal reproducible example, published.